# Unable to obtain exclusive access: Master - Detail

Tags: apex, master-detail, schedulebatch, roll-up-summary

We have a master detail relation from custom Invoice object to Account. There are bunch of roll-up summary fields on account calculated from invoice.

Other than roll up no where we have logic in triggers/ config where update of invoice record updates account record.

Issue: Lets say I have 2 accounts; A1 (Related invoice records: I1, I2, i3, I4) and A2 (Related invoice records: I5, I6, i7, I8). There is a nightly batch which grabs all invoice records (more than 1 million) and copies a formula field on invoice record to a static field on invoice itself.

`Formula field on invoice record : Today() - CreatedDate`

Once the batch runs nightly, we are getting this error.
`getMessage=unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 83 records:`

What I am assuming is when invoice record I4 is updated, rollup on Account record A1 are updated and when I3 is updated, system is not getting exclusive access on the parent record as it is the parent account records that are getting locked

Is my assumption correct? If yes/ no, can someone point me in right direction.

Comment: Ask support if they can run the record locking diagnostics tools (dashboard, really) on your org - have timestamps of when you hit this error handy so they know when to look.

Comment: I have the timestamp of when these errors are happening as I am using database.saveresult and if not is success I am creating a record in error logger object. So I have timestamps... contact support with these timestamps and ask them to run diagnostic tools ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

Your batch job is processing the operation from multiple threads and it is trying to lock the same parent record because of rollup summary on Account object.

> Workaround will be, limit the batch size and process the records in Serial mode, rather than parallel, so that system can obtain exclusive lock on Parent account.

Refer [The Salesforce Bulk API - Maximizing Parallelism and Throughput Performance When Integrating or Loading Large Data Volumes](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Boral for clarifying.  Is there a keyword or how can we specify batch to run in serial mode rather than parallel ?

Comment: Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes

Comment: I went through the documentation but unable to understand where exactly in my batch class should I make that change to change the concurrency mode from parallel to serial

Comment: you can put a separate question, with your code. You need to change the concurrencyMode as Serial

Comment: @SantanuBoral Batch jobs are not parallel, ever, today. (I work for Salesforce and once asked the team who built batch about this)

Comment: @ca_peterson thats good to know from you